# ParameterizedType.getRawType() returns j.l.r.Type, not Class<?>?

Tags: java, reflection

```
ParameterizedType parameterized =
    (ParameterizedType) List.class.getMethod("iterator").getGenericReturnType();
Type raw = parameterized.getRawType();
```

`ParameterizedType#getRawType()` returns a `Type`, not a `Class<?>` (although I get that `java.lang.Class` now implements `Type`). Is there a good reason why `getRawType()` doesn't declare its return type to be `Class<?>`? Are there extreme cases where `getRawType()`'s result might not be a `Class<?>`?

It's enough of a thrashing to work with `j.l.r.Type` as it is; this seems like an instance in which they could have saved us one downcast.

Comment: This thread http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t524488-raw-type-other-than-a-class-possible.html indicates the return type is alway a Class, but I'm also looking for further opinions on this.

Comment: Looks like basic separation of interface and implementation to me. The Javadoc lists `Class` as the only implementation of `Type`, but the JRE contains a couple of dozen protected classes that implement `Type` also.

Comment: I'd buy the separation of interface vs. implementation argument if `Type` weren't a marker interface. To do the things I'd like to do with a `Type`, I must test for whether it's a `Class<?>`, `ParameterizedType`, `WildcardType`, `GenericArrayType`, and such. If I could accomplish what I wanted with an arbitrary object just as a `Type`, it wouldn't matter so much to me whether the result's runtime class was `java.lang.Class`, or what have you.

Comment: @skaffman: That only shows that `Class` might be the only public and documented implementation in the jdk.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It must return a `Class` object, there's no other way.

Why? Who knows, maybe some idealistic bias. If it returned `Class`, it would be the only appearance of `Class` in the new `Type` interfaces.

The real problem is the mixing of `Class` and `Type`. Previously, all types are represented in `Class`. It was already messy, but still tolerable. There weren't very many types.

With the new generic types, they should have designed a cleaner and true-to-spec`Type` hierarchy independent of `Class`. Instead they incorporated `Class` with `Type` and created more mess. The entire hierarchy just doesn't make sense. Anyone new to the subject and unaware of the history will be appalled by this nonsense.

I wouldn't hold the design of `Type` to a high standard. For example, `ParameterizedType` defines `equals()`, but not `hashCode()`. There's no way to have two implementations of `ParameterizedType` work in one hash map. And wildcard is also a type? Hell no.

And the name of the method `getRawType()` is just idiotic. It has nothing to do with `raw type`. It should be plainly named `getClassOrInterface()`. Would it be too verbose? Look at `getActualTypeArguments()` then. (And yeah, it returns *actual* arguments! Not fake ones!)

Comment: `ParameterizedType` is just an interface, and doesn't define `equals()` or `hashCode()`.  `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl` appears to define both, at least in Sun JRE 1.5.0_22.  You can always convert the `ParameterizedTypeImpl`s you get from reflection to your own implementation of `ParameterizedType` if they don't behave how you want.

Comment: @Andy _Instances of classes that implement this interface must implement an equals() method that equates any two instances that share the same generic type declaration and have equal type parameters._ [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) But without a definition for `hashCode()` this is not very useful if you intend to use `ParameterizedType` instances in a `Set`. A solution could be to wrap all `ParameterizedType`s in an implementation with a custom `hashCode()` method, to make sure `equal` entries return the same `hashCode`.

Answer (score 5):

I was thinking about this, and I have a hunch.  Perhaps they wanted to leave the possibility open for future craziness like this:

```
public class Z<L extends List<?>> {
    L<Double> test;
}
```

This is not legal Java code, but I think it's clear what it would mean; `new Z<ArrayList<?>>().test` would be of type `ArrayList<Double>`.

If this were legal, `((ParameterizedType) test.getGenericType()).getRawType()` would return a `TypeVariable`.

Answer (score 3):

Sun's implementation of `ParameterizedType` has defined the `getRawType()` method to return `Class<?>`. So it clearly returns only `Class<?>`

However, on my classpath there are a few more implementations of `ParameterizedType` - from hibernate-validator, from aspectj, hibernate-annotations, jaxb. Some of them return `Class<?>`, some - `Type`. I don't know how they are used though.

Comment: huh? It returns a `Type` http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getRawType() **edit** ok, which only `class` implements.

Comment: I said the implementation. `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl`

Comment: The weird thing is `ParameterizedTypeImpl.getOwnerType()` returns a `Type`!

Answer (score 3):

There are other uses for the Type interface hierarchy than just the reflection api. For instance, a code generation library may define custom implementations. The JDK 8 itself has 3 different implementations of WildcardType. If ParameterizedType.getRawType() returned a Class instance, then you'd need to be able to create a Class instance whenever you want.

A Class is a very deeply-ingrained-in-the-JVM type that has bindings back to native-managed memory. To create a Class instance, you must have the byte code that defines the class. But in the case of a code generation library, the byte code doesn't even exist yet. If they had required the ParameterizedType to return a Class, it would limit the applicability of the Type interface hierarchy to only the reflection api.

This may not seem like a big deal, but neither is a cast.

ParameterizedType.getOwnerType() returns a Type as it may itself be either a Class or another ParameterizedType. It may in theory return a TypeVariable, as the following is valid Java:

```
<M extends Map<?,?>> M.Entry<?,?> first(M map) { ... }
```

However, it's compiled as a static reference to the type variable's erasure, in this case M.Entry would be compiled as Map.Entry. Instead of a TypeVariable, a call to getOwnerType() from the reflection api will be a Class, at least according to my tests.